# jWysiwyg jQuery large space after Controls and above textarea

Tags: jquery, jwysiwyg

I get a large space (about 300px) after the controls and before the textarea? in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9. I have tried with the default jWysiwyg but get the same thing.

```
function($) {
$('#news').wysiwyg({
controls: {
  strikeThrough : { visible : true },
  underline     : { visible : true },
  separator00 : { visible : false },

  justifyLeft   : { visible : true },
  justifyCenter : { visible : true },
  justifyRight  : { visible : true },
  justifyFull   : { visible : true },

  separator01 : { visible : true },

  indent  : { visible : true },
  outdent : { visible : true },

  separator02 : { visible : true },

  subscript   : { visible : true },
  superscript : { visible : true },

  separator03 : { visible : true },

  undo : { visible : true },
  redo : { visible : true },

  separator04 : { visible : true },

  insertOrderedList    : { visible : true },
  insertUnorderedList  : { visible : true },
  insertHorizontalRule : { visible : true },

  separator07 : { visible : true },

  cut   : { visible : true },
  copy  : { visible : true },
  paste : { visible : true }
},css : "ttwcadm.css" 
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

And my HTML is

```
<form method="post" id="newsform" action="index.php?page=6">
    <textarea id="news" name="news">
        <?php include($newsfile); ?>
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Please post the rendered html and its related CSS, No way to determine what is affecting the layout with above information.

Comment: #news {
     width:100%;
     height:350px;
     }

Comment: Above is the CSS I am using. How do I show the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with your css style; floating elements and such. After initialising jWysiwyg on a textarea, also add this line of code:

```
$('div.wysiwyg div').removeAttr('style');
```

This is because there is a div after the Toolbar with a style tag of "clear: both;". The code above removes the style tag and fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by a floated element to the left of the textarea. The space was the height of the floated element! Work around was to float the div containing the textarea.
Hope this helps